# Haskell, finding element in bst

Tags: haskell

```
data Bst a = Empty | Node (Bst a) a (Bst a)

lElems :: Ord a => a -> Bst a -> Int
lElems _ Empty = -1
lElems n (Node l m r)
                | n == m = n
                | n > m = lElems n r
                | n < m = lElems n l
```

Here you see definition of type and program. I want to return element if it's in the tree and -1 if not.

```
However, I had this problem 
 Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for lElems :: Ord a => a -> Bst a -> Int
          at C:\Users\User\workspace\s\src\Main.hs:3:11
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong here?

Comment: "I want to return element if it's in the tree and -1 if not" -- if the elements are not numbers, there's no type that includes both -1 and the element values. Consider using Haskell-style `Maybe` instead of broken C-style error reporting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `n == m` case, `lElems` returns `n`. From the type signature, the function is declared as always returning `Int`. This means that `n` *must* be an `Int`, and thus, can't be *any* `Ord a`.

<s>Try converting `n` into `Int` before returning it;</s> that will probably require you to further constrain `a`, though.

Instead of returning `-1` in the case where you don't find what you're looking for, consider changing the return type to `Maybe a`, or perhaps an `Either` value.